# PHP RegExp exclusion

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

i need to write regexp which match to strings:

- lorem,ipsum,45,56
- lorem123,ipsum56743,dolor34,78,86
- lorem-123,ipsum5678,dolor654,12,45,90
- 1230-lorem,234-ips546um-234,12,56,78

but doesn't match to strings:

- 123-456-ABC20089
- 12-4-ABC123456

My regexp doesn't work, because it match to last strings:

```
([a-z0-9,\-]*)
```

How can I exclude that?

Comment: I don't get the criteria for matching and not matching. Is comma mandatory for matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following as your regex (which matches the offending strings):

```
\d+\-\d+\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Then in your PHP code you want to check for the opposite of the match:

```
<?php
$subject = "123-456-ABC20089";
$pattern = '/\d+\-\d+\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+/';
if(!preg_match($pattern, $subject)
{
    // it doesn't match
}
else
{
    // it does match, move along
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

with ^, which is the negate operator for reg exes.
But here you just want to negate ","

```
(^[,]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([a-z0-9\-]+,)+[a-z0-9\-]+
```

Matches two or more "words", separated by commas. Is that what you're looking for?